# How to mark failed TODO on Emacs org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am trying to make a TODO checkbox on org-mode appear as failed.

What I mean by that is that I do not want the checkbox to appear as `- [X]`, but rather something that would indicate that the task at hand has failed.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: It's just text, so you can put it in whatever character you choose to indicate failure.

Comment: You can create TODO keyword with C-h v org-todo-keywords or  per file  as "#+TODO: TODO FEEDBACK VERIFY | DONE FAILED" at the top of file.